# How to get Google Test to execute multiple test files in QtCreator?

Tags: c++, qt, googletest

I used Google Test in Qt Creator and wrote two test files, one is tst_a.h(**generated by default**).
The other file is **tst_b.h**, which I created automatically, but only **tst_a.h** is executed during unit test.
How can I get Google Test to execute **tst_b.h**?

Please find contents of files mentioned above.

This is **tst_a.h**

```cpp
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock-matchers.h>
#include "Decimal.hpp"
using namespace testing;
TEST(contractTestCase, contractTestSet)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
    ASSERT_THAT(0, Eq(0));
}
```

this is **tst_b.h**

```cpp
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock-matchers.h>

using namespace testing;
TEST(testNormal, contractNormalTestSet)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write your tests in header files these header files need to be included in a cpp for them to be seen by the compiler. The default test setup starts out with a main.cpp in which you can add the include for your new .h file.